# Hibernate mapping a map of strings

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following table

```
userId
accountNumber
role
```

where each userId can have many roles for many accountNumbers.

I'd love to be able to make a map like the following..

```
public class User 
{
   Map<String, List<String>> rolesPerAccountNumber;
}
```

Is this possible or is there something similar I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won work. You would be better off putting it in a separate table(@Entity).